# Can I specify the default backup location for non-automatic backups?

Tags: backup, db2

I noticed that when the `BACKUP DATABASE` command is issued without the `TO` clause the backup file is stored to the working directory where the command is issued.

I'm wondering if it's possible to configure a default location for backups such that it's used when the location is not specified in the command.

What if the free space on the storage is not enough? Is there a setting to tell DB2 to automatically remove the oldest backup as for circular logging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to specify a default location.  The best way to do this would be to write a shell script (which specifies your location of choice) to handle your backups.

You can have DB2 remove old backups (using the `AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ` database configuration parameter with proper values for `NUM_DB_BACKUPS` and `REC_HIS_RETENTN`), but that will only occur after a successful backup.

So you'll need to ensure that there is enough space for the backup to complete successfully.

Comment: And archiving logs to disk..... From what I have experienced even logretain doesn't clean up logs. Just a point I figured worth mentioning.

Comment: @ChrisAldrich Yes, that's correct.  Setting LOGRETAIN does just what it says - retains logs.  :-)

Comment: Yup. That's why I thought I would mention it. I first assumed AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ would clean up logs as well when LOGRETAIN was set. Nope. Took me a bit to figure out I needed to set logs to DISK. Just figured it was worth mentioning here for others to not get caught on that one.